# Failed Check Component Dependency 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.2.5, dependency, component

How do I get Fix this Error?

```
Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information


[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 
failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found) 


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>].
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

you need enable `allow_url_fopen`.

You can check whether the `allow_url_fopen` is enabled by executing the following command in the root Magento 2 folder:

```
php -i | grep allow_url_fopen
```

Edit your `php.ini`, find `allow_url_fopen` and set it to `allow_url_fopen = 1`

Comment: THANK YOU !!!   It was only turned on in the sub directory for the new domain. I had to turn it on for main domain website as well for it to work.  It did.

Comment: so your problem solve?